# How do I test difference in Percentages?

Tags: binomial-distribution, z-test, percentage

I have some survey data and know the number and percentage of "yes" responses.  How do I determine if any of the percentage yes regional responses are statistically different from the national yes response percentage.

[image: Response data]

Answer (score 2):

**Use a hypergeometric test to see whether each region's proportion is significantly greater or significantly less than the national proportion.**

The hypergeometric test treats the population as a bag with 21568 stones, 10820 of which are white. Each region is then treated as a random sample from that bag. For example the North East is like grabbing 1919 of those stones and getting 1032 white ones. You can calculate how unlikely that sample is in R:

```
> phyper(1032-1, 10820, 21568-10820, 1919, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.0004970996
```

The `0.0004970996` says there's there's a very small chance that randomly drawing from the national votes 1919 times will give you 1032 yeses. I.e. this tests whether the proportion of North East yeses is significantly different than the population average, and it is (p = 0.0004).

However, you're also interested in whether the regional proportion is significantly *less* than the national average! To calculate that you can use the `lower.tail=T` option:

```
> phyper(1031, 10820, 10748, 1919, lower.tail = T)
[1] 0.9995029
```

So the North East's proportion looks significantly greater than the national average (p = 0.0004) and not significantly less (p = 0.9995).

To answer your question you could repeat this process of testing both tails for each region. Since this means conducting 26 hypothesis tests, you could expect that one or two might be significant just by random chance if you're using a threshold like p<0.05. For that reason I'd finish the analysis off with a multiple comparison correction.